# How to use Azure VPN as a proxy gateway

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have followed [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal) to set up a Point-to-Site VPN connection to an Azure Virtual Network which
contains my Azure Windows Virtual Machine. I successfully managed to get to my VM via its private IP address e.g., doing Remote Desktop.

Now my question is how to use this VPN connection as a proxy gateway; i.e., all the traffic from my PC goes through the Virtual Network or the Virtual Machine?

Any article or hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you want all the traffic from your local PC to go through the VPN gateway. Perhaps, you just want to restrict to access Azure resources via the VPN gateway, if so, that is the VPN gateway itself that can do it. You just need to access azure resources with the VPN client's private IP address with a VPN connection.

Essentially, a VPN gateway sends encrypted traffic between your virtual network and your on-premises location across a public connection. By default, the outbound traffic from your local PC goes through to the Internet with a default route via the local network gateway. Before you can connect to the VPN gateway, you need to ensure that there is networking connectivity from the local PC to the Azure VPN gateway public IP address.

### Update

Unfortunately, Azure P2S VPN by default uses split tunneling. it's not supported to route all the traffic from your PC to go through the VPN gateway. See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f1300322-8eee-4d2d-ae42-cafff52c1bb1/is-it-possible-to-route-all-client-internet-traffic-through-azure-pointtosite-vpn) and you could vote up [this feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/7027397-use-p2s-vpn-connection-as-default-gateway-like-st).

Here is a suggestion from the Azure feedback team.

> 1. Use default route or forced tunneling on P2S client rather than split tunneling.
> 2. Enable Azure VPN gateway as a forward proxy to the Internet.

Comment: The reason for "having all traffic from my local PC to go through the VPN gateway" may sound weird but simple. Some of Azure services are not being offered in my country.

Comment: Do you want to access these Azure service with a VPN gateway?  When you connect it with a VPN gateway, there is a route to your azure vnet with a VPN gateway. Does this you expect? I mean this is how Azure VPN will do, you don't need to add extra route or other function.

Comment: I think chit-chatting about the reason is not constructive regarding the question. In simple words, I kind of want to be seen as if I am working from another country.

Comment: Does this updated information in my reply help you?

Comment: Sorry no it doesn't help

Comment: Do you consider other VPN gateways instead of Azure VPN gateway because it's not supported to work as proxy gateway currently.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your last comment. Just to clarify, I'm happy to use P2S Azure VPN to connect to Azure Virtual Network, then use a VPN gateway to connect to my VM, and then route all the traffic from my PC to go through the VPN gateway to my VM. Not sure this is possible at all.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to route all traffic from your PC through the VPN gateway. As I said before when you use Azure VPN gateway, all the traffic from your PC not only can go through the VPN gateway to your Azure VM but also the traffic from your PC can go out over the public network.

Comment: Azure VPN is trash. cant even route traffic through the VPN like every single other VPN out there. WHY WHY WHY are they so incompetent?